# Reading doc and docx files using C# without having MS Office installed on server

Tags: c#, docx, doc

I'm working on a project (asp.net, c#, vb 2010, .net 4) and I need to read both DOC and DOCX files, that I've previosly uploaded (I've done uploading part). Tricky part is that I don't have MS Office installed on server and that I can't use it.

Is there any public library that I can include into my project without having to install anything? 
Both docs are very simple:

```
NUMBER TAB STRING  
NUMBER TAB STRING  
NUMBER TAB STRING  
...
```

I need to extract number and string for each row (paragraph).

May someone help with this? I should repeat once again that I'm limited in a way that I can't install anything on a server.

Comment: doc AND docx? docx is a zip style compressed archive of XML documents and possibl binary (if images are in there etc.), doc is binary coded - totally different engine needed.

Comment: For DOCX there are free and commercial libraries BUT for DOC the only options I know of are commercial... Is a commercial library an option ?

Comment: @TomTom Yes I know that there is different background for doc and docx, but i'm interested if that can be somehow merged into one library? Or are there maybe two libraries that I can later merge on my own...
Thanks

Comment: 2 libraries definitely. And likely a Commercial one for .doc

Comment: You totally do not need a commercial library. Well, unless you really can't install *anything*, rather than just not being able to install large, client-facing applications. Otherwise, you can use the [Office IFilter](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20109), which is technically installing *something*, but wouldn't a third-party library also also be something?

Answer (score 5):

We can now use open source, [NPOI](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=npoi) (.NET port of Apache POI) library which also supports docx, xls & xlsx.
DocX is also another open source library for creating word docs.

For DOCX I'd suggest [Open XML API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb656295%28office.12%29.aspx), though Microsoft developed **Open XML** to create office files through the XML files communicating with this API, the latest version 2.5 was released in 2013 which is 5 years ago.

Comment: According to the NPOI link you provided it says "Support xls, xlsx, docx." - there no mention whatsoever of DOC !!!

Comment: @Yahia Hm... Commercial library would no be such good solution. If you know a public one, that would be great :)

As for NPOI, yes I've also seen that it is not supporting DOC files :(

Comment: Good news, it now supports both 2003 and 2007 files: "POI is an open source project which can help you read/write Office 2003/2007 files". And yes, doc is not stable (http://npoi.codeplex.com/discussions/360441)...

Answer (score 2):

you can use [Code7248.word_reader.dll](https://sourceforge.net/p/word-reader/wiki/Home/)

below is the sample code on how to use Code7248.word_reader.dll

add reference to this DLL in your project and copy below code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
//add extra namespaces
using Code7248.word_reader;


namespace testWordRead
{
    class Program
    {
        private void readFileContent(string path)
        {
            TextExtractor extractor = new TextExtractor(path);
            string text = extractor.ExtractText();
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program cs = new Program();
            string path = "D:\Test\testdoc1.docx";
            cs.readFileContent(path);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know where can I view the license for this DLL? does its license support distribution of DLL to others?

Answer (score 1):

Update: NPOI supports docx now. Please try the latest release (NPOI 2.0 beta)

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Spire.Doc;
    
namespace ReadTextLineByLine{
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            //Create a Document object
            Document doc = new Document();
            //Load a Word file
            doc.LoadFromFile(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\data.docx");
            //Convert the text in Word line by line into a txt file
            doc.SaveToTxt("result.text", Encoding.UTF8);
            //Read all lines of txt file
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("result.text", System.Text.Encoding.Default);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).