# Read text from a .doc or .docx file in asp.net using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, docx

I can upload a text file and read its text in a textbox.

Now I want to do the same for .doc or .docx files.

When I tried it in the similar way I read the text files I got some text which is in encrypted format in the whole document. The code for reading from a .txt file is as follows :

```
txtReadFiles.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Path)
```

can anyone suggest me some idea?

Comment: this is duplicate of question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455268/reading-doc-and-docx-files-using-c-sharp-without-having-ms-office-installed-on-s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455268/reading-doc-and-docx-files-using-c-sharp-without-having-ms-office-installed-on-s) you can also try [http://docx.codeplex.com/](http://docx.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is an [ifilter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFilter) for .doc(x) files. Ifilters were designed to be used by Windows for its indexing service, but they are frequently pressed into use also for other applications to read text from binary files that contain text. IFilters are frequently released for free - I believe [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20109) contains the correct ifilters for doc/docx files (and other Office files).

That said, I've never used the ifilter interface in .net, only in unmanaged c++, but it should be possible. A quick googling turned up [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13391/Using-IFilter-in-C) as a likely place to start (it has some recommendations of things to avoid, and some code. I make no guarantee that the code works, you might have to find something else. But the ifilter technology itself does work, I've used it in projects before. Other than the ifilter for pdfs that ships with Reader, which only just "works", barely, last I checked. The Office ifilters work fine, though.)

Answer (score 0):

`Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word 'above public class`

`If OpenFileDialogFile.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            TBfile.Text = OpenFileDialogFile.FileName 'alamat n nama file asli
            '-----------
            Dim ext As String
            ext = Path.GetExtension(OpenFileDialogFile.FileName)
            If ext = ".txt" Then
                'tampilkan isi file
                TB1.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(OpenFileDialogFile.FileName)
            ElseIf ext = ".doc" Then
                Dim App As Application = New Application
                Dim doc As Document
                Try
                    doc = App.Documents.Open(OpenFileDialogFile.FileName)
                    Dim co As Integer = doc.Words.Count
                    For i As Integer = 1 To co
                        Dim tex As String = doc.Words(i).Text
                        'tampilkan isi file
                        TB1.Text += tex
                    Next
                    doc.Close()
                Catch ex As Exception
                End Try
            ElseIf ext = ".docx" Then
                Dim App As Application = New Application
                Dim doc As Document
                Try
                    doc = App.Documents.Open(OpenFileDialogFile.FileName)
                    Dim co As Integer = doc.Words.Count
                    For i As Integer = 1 To co
                        Dim tex As String = doc.Words(i).Text
                        'tampilkan isi file
                        TB1.Text += tex
                    Next
                    doc.Close()
                Catch ex As Exception
                End Try
            End If
            '----------
        Else
            Call kosongkan()
            CBkunci1.Focus()
        End If`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your code correctly and consider adding context in addition to the code