# Read the word document conent without using Microsoft office

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I am using word documents for the population of random mails. But to read the content, we are using MS Word. But the scripts are quite slow because of its `auto-recovery` feature.

My code is in powershell, is there any other alternative to read word docs? I tried to use wordpad but no success.

Comment: If you don't want to use Microsoft Office Word, then change the format of the source document for "population of your random mails."

Comment: No, source document format can not be changed as per my requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are docx files then they are an OpenXML format. Several solutions exists of reading docx files from code without requiring Office. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011234/how-to-extract-text-from-ms-office-documents-in-c-sharp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455268/reading-doc-and-docx-files-using-c-sharp-without-having-ms-office-installed-on-s). They are in C# but translating that to PowerShell should prove little problems. Or have a go with [PowerTools for Open XML](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools) if you want to use PowerShell commands. [Here](http://ericwhite.com/blog/powertools-for-open-xml-expanded/) is some more documentation on that subject.

If you mean you want to view them in their final format like a normal user would do, but without office, you can use [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4) for example.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution with the help of `PowerTools for Open XML` `(Select-OpenXmlString -path $file_name).content`.
To use powerTools on many machines will need Visual Studio to be installed on all machines which is not very feasible. It is available at: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools

I have followed this screencast: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zU0utt3uga4.

And for other machines there is one small catch:

1. Copy the dlls by maintaining the folder structure
2. On the machine where you have built it. Copy the GAC C:\Windows\assembly\gac_msil\DocumentFormat.OpenXml and paste it to other machines where you want to use it.

Thanks Lars Truijens!!