# Open/Close word document application

Tags: powershell

We need to do some text search on word doc, and use below lines of code to open document. I got the code running on two laptops, in one it doesn't open wordapp and in other it does.

```
$objWord = New-Object -Com Word.Application
$objWord.Visible = $false 
$objDocument = $objWord.Documents.Open($filename)
$objDocument.Close()
$objWord.Quit()
# Stop Winword Process
$rc = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objWord)
```

Is there any other way of opening document, as this open WORD DOC application which we don't want that. How to scan document without letting Word application open?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read the word document conent without using Microsoft office](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835177/read-the-word-document-conent-without-using-microsoft-office)

Comment: Use [Powertools](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=powertools)